# How to wait for server response before proceeding to next call in ClojureScript?

Tags: ajax, clojure, callback, async-await, clojurescript

```
(def tables (atom nil)) 

(defn validateDatasource [datasource]
        (get-tables tables)
        (js/console.log @tables)
    )

(defn get-tables [tables]
    (ajax/GET "/tables"
    {:headers {"Accept" "application/transit+json"}
    :handler #(reset! tables (vec %))}
    ))
```

Here I am calling the **validateDatasource**  on a button click and **at first click it is printing null**..
But after sometime if i **click again it is printing the tables map in console.**

Thus I want to know how can i wait for the server response before i proceed with printing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct answer to your question is: you can't wait in browser-side javascript because javascript is strictly asynchronous and single-threaded.

You choices are (1) write callback code, (2) write promise code, (3) use core.async.

**(1) Callbacks.**  Instead of trying to "wait" on the server to return (which you cannot do), pass the code as a callback:

```
(defn get-tables [result-atom next]
  (ajax/GET "/tables"
            {:headers {"Accept" "application/transit+json"}
             :handler (fn [response]
                        (reset! result-atom (vec response))
                        (next result-atom))})) ; This is the key line

(defn validate-datasource [datasource]
  (js/console.log datasource))

(defn get-and-validate-tables [result-atom]
  (get-tables result-atom validate-datasource))
```

Note, given that you are passing the atom as an argument (and shadowing the top-level definition), it is probably better to remove it entirely and just have the `handler` pass the response directly to `next` without messing with an atom.

**(2) Promises.**  Callbacks are fine if you only do one thing, but the moment you try to chain more than one together it will get complicated.  You can use the [promesa](http://funcool.github.io/promesa/latest/) library to write promise code that make callbacks easier to deal with.

```
(defn get-tables
  []
  (promesa/promise
    (fn [resolve reject]
      (ajax/GET "/tables"
                {:headers {"Accept" "application/transit+json"}
                 :handler resolve
                 :error-handler reject}))))

;; Note, this function returns a promise, so you can call then and catch on it
(get-tables-and-validate []
  (-> (get-tables)
      (promesa/then (fn [response]
                      (validate-datasource response)))
      (promesa/catch (fn [error]
                       (js/console.log error)))))
```

This is nice because you can chain promise-returning calls together using the calls to `then`.  Error handling works well too.

**3.  Core.async.**  You can also try using the core.async library, but I'll warn you that it introduces a lot of complexity and code that you probably don't need.  It also is pretty awkward to deal with exceptions and I've hit corner cases and bugs with it without doing anything all that complicated.  In my opinion, the promise code above is more robust and easier to follow.

Finally, if atom validation is really all you want, note that you could use `set-validator!` on your atom.

```
(set-validator! tables (fn [atm] (validate-datasource atm)))
```

Now whenever you update the `tables` atom, the validator will run automatically.

Answer (score 0):

`ajax/GET` is an async call. This means it returns immediatelly, without waiting for a response from server.

You might want to use `core.async` or, if it suites you, manifold library. There is a [port to CLJS](https://github.com/dm3/manifold-cljs).

Comment: So is there a problem in my function call orders?

Comment: Yes. Look [here](http://dimagog.github.io/blog/clojure/clojurescript/2013/07/12/making-http-requests-from-clojurescript-with-core.async/) for a possible solution.